# Woocommerce email subject placeholders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am need of customer name and some other details in the subject of the emails. 
I also referred to Email variables and merge tags

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/email-variables-and-merge-tags/

But when I used {customer_first_name} in the subject portion, the same thing is being displayed in the email insted of the real customer name

[image: click to view img]

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to [the doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-email-subject-lines/), the function should be something like:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);

function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $subject = sprintf( 'New order:', $order->billing_first_name );

    return $subject;
}
```